# How can I make the sub drop-down appear in default (collapsed) structure

Tags: javascript, html

I have a drop down list with multi drop downs, which opens and closes on alternative clicks but when I try to reopen the drop down the entire drops appear without closing. How can i make it appear on default structure.
please help guys. Thanks in advance

```
<style>
.closed{display:none;}
.opened{display:block;}
</style>
<div class="dropdown">
<p class=" dropdown-toggle" type="" data-toggle="dropdown" 
style="padding: 15px 0px;font-size: 24px;"><i class="fas fa-bars">
</i>&nbsp;CATEGORY</p>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu opened">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu opened">
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu closed">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu closed">
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
//new drop ends
$(function(){
$('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){                  
    var ul = $(this).next('ul');
    if(ul.hasClass('opened')){
        ul.removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');
    }else{
        ul.addClass('opened').removeClass('closed');
    }
    if($(this).parents('ul').length == 1){
        $(this).parents('ul').find('ul').not(ul).addClass('closed').removeClass('opened')
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

});        
});  
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the modified classes are:

[image]

The answer, remove "opened" class in dropdown-menus.

```
        <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
            <li>
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

***Replace jQuery code for:***

```
    $('.dropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
        $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').each(function () {
            var ul = $(this).next('ul');
            if (ul.hasClass('opened')) {
                ul.removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');
            } else {
                ul.addClass('opened').removeClass('closed');
            }
            if ($(this).parents('ul').length) {
                $(this).parents('ul').find('ul').not(ul).addClass('closed').removeClass('opened')
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Comment: what do you mean about default structure ? 
This ? https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3

Comment: the drops should come in unopened state

Comment: You when open the HTML page, dropdown closed right ?, then when click the first dropdown shows the first level, when click the last element of the first open the next one right.. ?

Comment: yes but when i close and open again it should come in default structure ie multi drops closed